# meaning of the phrase "as now" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from Crash Course World History. It is at 6 minute and 53 second. Here it goes:

> Although soldiers lived then, **as now**, under conditions it is difficult to imagine, there was more then even the threat of death to distress them.

I cannot get whether speaker means by *as now*  that the conditions were much horrible in the past, or that they are as horrible as in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase

> **as now**

is used to compare the *current times* with the past

> Although soldiers lived then, **as now**,
>   *Although soldiers lived back then, as they do nowadays*,

The writer is saying both now and in the past conditions are horrible.